# How can you prove that a value raised to $\frac{1}{n}$ is the n'th root of $x$?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation, radicals

I know that if you raise a value to $\frac{1}{2}$ for example, you take the square root, but that is not what I am asking, what I am asking is; what are you actually doing when raising a value to $\frac{1}{2}$ apart from figuring out which number multiplied by it self gives you that first value?
For example, if you raise $4$ to the power of $2$ you multiply $4$ by itself, obviously, but what do you do when you have $\frac{1}{2}$ as an exponent for example?

This is something that all through out my school years(this far, I am in High School) has not been explained.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "numerically."

Comment: By your above comments, are you not accepting the answer $a^{1/2}$ is a solution to $x^2 = a$?

Comment: @Tom If you were reffering to me, then yes I do accept that to be the answer. But what I dont understand is what are you actually doing when raising to the half power apart from going through the numbers in your head that can be multiplied to get the value you are raising to the half power?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to see it, before calculus, is to just realize that if we want to keep the "nice" property of integer exponentiation:

$$\left(x^n\right)^m = x^{nm}$$ for rational exponentiation, we want to define $x^{p/q}$ so that $$\left(x^{p/q}\right)^q=x^p$$

That this works is due to something deeper going on that requires some knowledge of calculus, and, in fact, even more deeply, complex numbers. And even then, it is mysterious - it is the kind of thing a mathematician gets deeper and deeper understanding of as one gets older.

Numerically, we can define a function:

$$\exp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Sorry for the notation - I realize that it is a bit confusing if you haven't covered calculus, and perhaps even if you have. $n!$ is the product of the first $n$ positive integers $n! = n\cdot(n-1)\cdots2\cdot 1$ with $0!=1$ by definition, and this notation means that we add up all possible values of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$. So this formula looks like:

$$\exp(x) = 1 + \frac{x^1}{1} + \frac{x^2}{2\cdot 1} + \frac{x^3}{3\cdot2\cdot 1} + \frac{x^4}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}\cdots$$
Then we prove that this is defined for all real (or even complex) $x$, and then show that $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$, that $\exp(0)=1$, and define $e=\exp(1)$ and show that $e\neq 1$.

This means that $\exp(n)=e^n$ for any integer $n$, so we often write $\exp(x)=e^x$.

We can also define, in several different ways, the natural logarithm of positive $x$, $\ln x$ so that $\ln(\exp(x))= x$.

This in turn lets us define $x^y$ for any $y$ and $x>0$ - namely, by defining $$x^y = \exp(y\ln x)$$

This gets more fun when you get to complex numbers. In general, $x^y$ has one possible complex value if $y$ is an integer, it as $q$ possible values if $y=p/q$ is a reduced rational number with $q\geq 1$, and $x^y$ has infinitely many possible values when $y$ is irrational.

Comment: $\exp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ proves what happens if you were to raise e to a fraction since in the summation term you are never actually raising anything to a fraction which makes the the whole equation a non-circular proof. Am I correct on this?

Comment: @Reds I'm not sure it "proves" what happens when you raise $e$ to a fraction.  Just because $\exp(n)=e^n$ and $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$ doesn't mean we *know* that $\exp(x)=e^x$ is meaningful notation. It is reason to think it could be, however, and it turns out that $\exp(x)$ is fundamental in a lot of ways, so we except the notation $\exp(x)=e^x$. But, as you say, one nice thing is that it is not circular. (You still have to do an infinite sum, however.)

Comment: There is another way to define $\exp(x)$ - namely, as the limit: $$\exp(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac x n\right)^n$$ This limit can be seen as getting $x$ interest from your bank, compounded instantaneously. You can also think of fractional exponentiation in terms of interest - if you are getting $7\%$ interest per year from your bank, with is the correct amount they should give you after $11$ months? Turns out, to be "fair" it should be $1.07^{11/12}$.

Comment: But these exp(x) equation don't really tell us much about a case in which you were to raise an integer for example, to a fraction, do they?

Comment: Nope, indeed, when $x$ is an integer, the general formula for $x^y=e^{y\ln x}$ is still quite complicated, since $\ln x$ is messy. $\exp(x)$ is, in some sense, the most "natural" exponentiation for fractional exponents. That is why we call $\ln x$ the "natural logarithm."  (You can actually redo my argument above by first defining $\ln x$, as as an area under a curve, rather the $\exp(x)$, then defining $\exp(x)$ as the inverse.)

Answer (score 0):

I find this question interesting.

Take the cuberoot of 2 as an example which can be written as:

$$\sqrt[3]{2} = 1.25992...$$

$$2{}^{1/3} = 1.25992...$$

The conventional way to define this operation is as pointed out in Thomas Andrews answer:

$$\exp \left(\frac{\log (2)}{3}\right) = 1.25992...$$

That is the exponential of the logarithm of 2 divided by 3. Division by three as in cube root. Logarithm of 2 as in the number to take the cube root of. But what then is a logarithm?

The exponential function is easy to understand, but the logarithm? One way to find a logarithm is to take a limit:

$$1 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{1/1}}\right) = 0.5$$

$$10 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{1/10}}\right) = 0.66967...$$

$$100 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{1/100}}\right) = 0.69075...$$

$$1000 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{1/1000}}\right) = 0.692907...$$

$$10000 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{1/10000}}\right) = 0.693123...$$

$$100000 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{1/100000}}\right) = 0.693145...$$

$$1000000 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{1/1000000}}\right) = 0.693147...$$

which converges to logarithm of 2:

$$\text{log}(2) = 0.693147...$$

But the problem persists, what do you do when you raise a number to a fraction?

---

After the discussion below this comes to mind:

$$\displaystyle \log(2) = \lim_{k\to \infty } \, \sum\limits_{n=k}^{2 k} \frac{1}{n}$$

$$\displaystyle \log(2) = \lim_{k\to \infty } \, \int\limits_k^{2 k} \frac{1}{n} \, dn$$

Comment: Of course, the problem is: how do you define $\log$ in general until you have defined general exponentiation? (Yes, you can define natural logarithms in terms of an integral, but that's not obvious.)

Comment: Yes, or perhaps not so much about defining, since I am not sure what it means to define something. But I agree, how do you compute the logarithm? I have Murray R. Spiegel's Mathematical Handbook which tells me how to compute a logarithm for x > 0. But I have yet to learn a few things about logarithms, I think.